# How to add Row Numbers and GROUP BY in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, row-number

I have a table like this:

[image: Tabel1]

Now I wish to GROUP BY the Field1, which is not that hard. After this, I want to add a row number to each group. And finally.. this has to be done in Access which is slightly different of course. So this is the code I have:

```
SELECT A.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tabel1 WHERE A.ID>=ID) AS RowNum
FROM Tabel1 AS A
ORDER BY A.ID;
```

[image: Result]

So, this works well, but now I can't group it. How can I group it?

Comment: Can' you use the ROW_NUMBER()  function in access?

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: @Vijey-- I don't believe MS Access supports windowing functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your entire query in a subquery:

```
select
  B.*
from
( SELECT
    A.*,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tabel1 WHERE A.ID>=ID) AS RowNum
  FROM Tabel1 AS A
) as B
ORDER BY B.ID;
```

From here, you can do joins as though the output of your query was a table.  I have no idea what you actually want to group on, but here is an example:

```
select
  B.Field1, count (*) as count, max (B.RowNum) as max_row
from
( SELECT
    A.*,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tabel1 WHERE A.ID>=ID) AS RowNum
  FROM Tabel1 AS A
) as B
group by
  b.Field1
```

-- Edit 11/14/2016 --

I think I see now.  In that case, first build a query to handle your grouping.  This is just an example:

```
SELECT Field1, min (Id) as min_id, max (id) as max_id
FROM Table1
group by Field1
```

Name this query `Table1_Summary` for the purposes of our example.

Now, in your new query, you will refer to Table1_Summary in the exact same way you did with your example:

```
SELECT 
  t.*,
  (select count (*) from Table1_Summary t2 where t.Field1 >= t2.Field1) as RowNum
FROM Table1_Summary t
```

You could theoretically do this in a single query, but for readability/maintainability sake, I'd recommend you keep them split.  Here is an example of the output:

[image]