# Why can't I get GROUP BY to work in my LEFT JOIN in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to populate a combobox from two tables in Access (2007-2016 file format).
I have two tables:

**tblSurveyStatus**

| SurveyID | SurveyStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Y |
| 2 | N |
| 3 | N/A |

**tblWorkOrder**

| WONumber | SurveyedID |
| --- | --- |
| WO2101 | 1 |
| WO2102 | 1 |
| WO2103 | 2 |
| WO2104 | 3 |
| WO2105 | 2 |
| WO2106 | {Empty} |
| WO2107 | {Empty} |

**Desired Result:**

| WONumber(this col will get hidden) | SurveyStatus |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| WO2101 | Y |
| WO2103 | N |
| WO2104 | N/A |

This query works in the datasource for the combobox without using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT SurveyedID, SurveyStatus
FROM [tblWorkOrders] a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SurveyID, SurveyStatus
    FROM [tblSurveyStatus] 
) b
ON a.SurveyedID = b.SurveyID
ORDER BY b.SurveyID
```

The problem with this query is that it returns duplicates (Y,Y,N,N,N/A).

So I introduced the GROUP BY like this:

```
SELECT SurveyedID, SurveyStatus
FROM [tblWorkOrders] a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SurveyID, SurveyStatus
    FROM [tblSurveyStatus] 
) b
ON a.SurveyedID = b.SurveyID
GROUP BY a.SurveyStatus ORDER BY b.SurveyID
```

This causes an error message "Your query does not include the specified expression 'SurveyedID' as part of an aggregate function." So, I put `MIN(SurveyedID)` and the error message moves to the next field so I keep putting MIN() in the SQL until finally it works but, I get an input box asking for the "SurveyStatus" then another one asking for the "SurveyID".

I have spent three solid days researching, reading threads on this website and many others without success. I am not a programmer but I kind of understand the basics. My programming basically comes from finding snippets of code and altering them for my use. Please Help!

Comment: Have a read of `DISTINCT`

Comment: Can you explain the semantics of what you want in the combo box? It looks like you want all the possible survey status values that are used in the work order table , but how are you deciding which duplicated work orders to exclude?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Row Numbers and GROUP BY in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550741/how-to-add-row-numbers-and-group-by-in-access)

Comment: I only need to pull up the first (or any) WONumber containing each of the SurveyStatus. Once I select one from the combobox, it will find that record, then set focus on the SurveyedStatus and filter to show all records with that status. Hope that helps you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 columns : SurveyedID, SurveyStatus in your 'select' expression while in 'group by' you are using only SurveyStatus which is not valid. All   non-aggregate columns in select should be used in 'group by' as well. That is why by adding MIN() to those columns solved the error (which converted those non-aggregate columns to aggregate ones).

Adding "SurveyedID" also to your group by clause can resolve your issue here.

Also if your sole motive is to avoid duplicates , just use 'DISTINCT' before the list of columns in select expression

Comment: Same exact results. I tried it with and without the MIN()<br>SELECT Min(SurveyedID), MIN(SurveyStatus)
FROM [Work Orders] a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Min(SurveyID), MIN(SurveyStatus)
    FROM [tblSurveyStatus] 
) b
ON a.SurveyedID = b.SurveyID
GROUP BY a.SurveyStatus, a.SurveyedID
ORDER BY b.SurveyID